# FPDF - output dynamic file name

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm creating a PDF page from an html form, so my php looks like this (for example):

```
$pdf->Cell(0,0,$_POST['teacher_name'],0,2,'C');
```

What is my missing step that I can define that variable (teacher_name) to create my output file as:

```
$pdf->Output('homework-teacher_name.pdf', 'D');
```

and the teacher_name in the output is replaced by whatever is submitted in the form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$fileName = 'homework-' . $_POST['teacher_name'] . '.pdf';
$pdf->Output($fileName, 'D');
```

Remember to sanitize external inputs using [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Answer (score 0):

nb. order of Output() parameters! according to http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm ist should be:

```
$pdf->Output('D', $fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fullname = $row["fullname"];

$pdf_file_name = $fullname.".pdf";

$pdf->Output($pdf_file_name,'D');
```

It is working.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it